# SQLAlchemy: Set order of expressions in WHERE clause

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm performing some analysis on sqlalchemy statements (ultimately as part of a mocking utility). I'd like to be able to put the where clause into a canonical order, so that I can compare queries for equality.

I've figured out how to access the where clause, and even how to obtain a sorted version of the clauses:

```
sorted(q.whereclause.clauses)
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to update the query (or alternatively, obtain a new query) with the where clause in the set order.

Please don't suggest performing a query against the database to see if the queries return the same data.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `sqlalchemy` but can you not simply do `q.whereclause.clauses = sorted(q.whereclause.clauses)`?

Comment: Fair enough. I figured it couldn't hurt to ask!

Comment: @That1Guy Actually, I owe you an apology: it looks like I *didn't* try that :( Fortunately, it basically works, except that I need to wrap up the sorted to return it to the right type.

Comment: No harm done. I'm glad you've worked it out.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out one *can* assign to `whereclause.clauses`:

```
q.whereclause.clauses = BooleanClauseList(*sorted(q.whereclause.clauses))
```